# TinyMce Buttons’ size

Tags: html, css, tinymce

I have a little problem with integrating tinyMCE in my project.

It is only visual, everything works, but I would like it to be a little more “nice looking”
There is an example I base myself on:

http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/full.php

And there is a result in application:

http://hpics.li/ea9de6c

As you can see, the size of buttons is just huge. (They are stretched)

Here are options I use for this textarea :

```
     {
        theme: "modern",
        plugins: [
            "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak",
            "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen",
            "insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality",
            "emoticons template paste textcolor colorpicker textpattern"
        ],
        toolbar1: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image",
        toolbar2: "print preview media | forecolor backcolor emoticons",
        image_advtab: true,
        language: 'fr_FR'
    }
```

Thanks !

FYI, this is HTML declaration of this textarea, normally, it is not relevant, but just in case:

```
<textarea style="width: 100%; height: 200px;" data-bind="wysiwyg: SelectedBlog().Content, wysiwygConfig: Tools.Helper.TinyMceBlogOptions"></textarea>
```

Comment: I think you may have another style impacting this page, its going to be hard to tell from what you have provided.  Provide the CSS and the HTML for the page.

Comment: I was afraid of that. There is more than 3000 lines of CSS and page itself is not little :( I will try to investigate it

Comment: post a fiddle instead of an image

Comment: Hello. I cannot provide fiddle because the page is really big and there are a lot of moving parts before landing on this particular box